# html5 media attribute question

Tags: html

Do both of these media attributes values mean the same thing below? If not what does each mean? And are they both valid?

```
<source src="music.mp3" media="screen, (color)">
<source src="music.mp4" media="screen and (color)">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to mark the answer that best solves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/

They are not equivalent. The comma means OR, not AND. An `and` in the query means both sides of the test must be true to match. ie:

```
screen, (color) = is a screen or anything that supports color
screen and (color) = is a color screen
projection, screen and (color) = is any type of projector OR a color screen
```